# pandas dataframe to aws postgresql using sqlalchemy not injecting data to table

Tags: pandas, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am running this code:

```
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@aws_db_endpoint:5432/db')
print(bool(engine)) # <- just to keep track of the process

with engine.connect() as conn:
    print(bool(conn)) # <- just to keep track of the process

    df.to_sql('mytable', schema='public', con=conn, if_exists='append')
    print("end") # <- just to keep track of the process
```

I get the `true`, `true` and `end` which means I get the connection done and the `df.to_slq` executed.

THe problem is that the table in aws postresql is still with no data at all.

What I am doing wrong here?

[image: echo mesg]

[image: creating table]

Thanks

Comment: don't you need to replace this ```df.to_sql('mytable', schema='public', con=engine, if_exists='append')``` to ``df.to_sql('mytable', schema='public', con=conn, if_exists='append')``?

Comment: yes! was a typo. con=conn still not updating my table.

Comment: Do you get any meaningful messages if you turn on echo=True in the create_engine function as in ``engine = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@hostname/dbname",
                            encoding='latin1', echo=True)``?

Comment: no! all seems to work just fine but at the end: `2022-03-26 16:58:15,709 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK`

Comment: The error message does not indicate why there is a rollback? What kind of error message do you see?

Comment: I added the img of echo to the question!  The weird thing is that the code is creating a table that already exists in aws.

Comment: That is the entire message? When does the rollback message appear and does it indicate whether there is some kind of violation?

Comment: no.  That's weird but there's no violations.

Answer (score 1):

Using `engine.connect` like this I think requires that you call `commit()` explicitly.  You can see the explaination towards the end of the [Basic Usage](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html#basic-usage) :

> When the connection is returned to the pool for re-use, the pooling
> mechanism issues a rollback() call on the DBAPI connection so that any
> transactional state or locks are removed, and the connection is ready
> for its next use.

So in this case you need to call `conn.commit()`. You can always commit unless there is an exception by changing your usage to `engine.begin()`:

```py
# Commit is called unless an exception occurs.
with engine.begin() as conn:
    print(bool(conn)) # <- just to keep track of the process

    df.to_sql('mytable', schema='public', con=conn, if_exists='append')
    print("end") # <- just to keep track of the process
```

## Example

Here is an example based on the panda docs.  This script runs against an empty database, specifically `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` creates the tables in the db first so pandas is forced to append.

```py
import sys
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.schema import (
    Column,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
import pandas as pd


Base = declarative_base()


username, password, db = sys.argv[1:4]


engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=False)


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(8), index=True)


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


with engine.begin() as conn:
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'name': ['User 1', 'User 2', 'User 3']
    })

    df.to_sql('users', schema="public", con=conn, if_exists='append', index_label='id')


with engine.begin() as conn:
    for user in conn.execute(select(User)).all():
        print(user.name)
```

Comment: now I get `2022-03-27 00:41:48,534 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT` which I think it's correct but the table is not updating. wondering why

Comment: I'm not sure, it seems to work for me.  Maybe try including a larger snippet of your code and double check your assumptions, ie. the existing table's schema matches your dataframe, the dataframe has data in it, etc.